# Excel extract substring from string

Tags: microsoft-excel, extract, string

I am looking for a way to extract a variable length substring from a string.

My cells will look something like:

```
ABC - DEF
ABCDE - DEF
ABCD - ABC
```

I want to split the string at the `-` character, so the cells will become:

```
ABC
ABCDE
ABCD
```

This should be done with a formula and not VBScript.

I am using Excel 2010

**EDIT**

I found that the dataset doesn't always contain the `-` character, meaning there should be no change.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This problem can be broken down into two steps:

1. Find the index in the string of your desired split character (in this case, `"-"` or `" - "`).
2. Get the prefix substring from the beginning of the original text to the split index.

The `FIND` and `SEARCH` commands each would return the index of a given `needle` in a `haystack` (`FIND` is case-sensitive, `SEARCH` is case-insensitive and allows wildcards). Given that, we have:

```
FIND(search_text, source_cell, start_index)
```

or in this case:

```
FIND(" - ", A1, 1)
```

Once we have the index, we need the prefix of `source_cell` to do the "split". `MID` does just that:

```
MID(source_cell, start_index, num_characters)
```

Putting them both together, we have:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND(" - ",A1,1))
```

with A1 having text of `ABC - DEF` gives `ABC`.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding upon Andrew's answer based on your edit:
to find the character string to split at, we are using the `FIND` function.
If the `FIND` fails to locate the string given, it returns a `#VALUE?` error.  So we will need to check for this value and use a substitute value instead.

To check for any error value including `#VALUE`, we use the `ISERROR` function, thus:

```
=ISERROR(FIND(" - ", A1, 1))
```

that will be true if the `FIND` function can't find the " - " string in the A1 cell.  So we use that to decide which value to use:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" - ", A1, 1)), A1, MID(A1, 1, FIND(" - ", A1, 1)))
```

That says that if the find command returns an error, use the unmodified A1 cell.  Otherwise, do the `MID` function that Andrew already provided.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @AndrewColeson for your answer.

So just to add to that, if you want everything on the right hand side of the `-`, use this code:

> =MID(A1,LEN(B1)+3,LEN(A1))

Which is:

```
A1 = ABC - DEF
B1 = =MID(A1,1,FIND(" - ",A1,1))
    B1 = ABC
Therefore A1 = DEF
```

This code is great for if you have an undefined number of characters after the `-`.

For instance:

If you have:

```
ABC - DEFG
AB - CDEFGH
...
```

Comment: this does the trick also `=MID(a1,FIND("-",a1)+1,LEN(a1))` without any "extra-cellular" references )

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple way to extract the 5th character from the left from a text string in Excel:

Suppose the character string `ABCDEFGHIJ` is stored in cell A1 in an Excel Spreadsheet, then the following formula

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(A1,5),1)
```

produces the 5th character from the left in the string, namely `E`.

Comment: (Is there no `MID` function in Excel? I'm sure it exists in legacy Visual Basic, and it would be something like `=MID(A1, 5, 1)`)

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will remove a substring from `[TEXTCOLUMN_1]`

e.g: if you want to convert `-./thumb/hello.jpg` to `thumb/hello.jpg` then use the following formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE([TEXTCOLUMN_1],LEFT([TEXTCOLUMN_1],[NUM_OF_CHARACTERS]),)
```

`[TEXTCOLUMN_1]` = the column name which you want to change
`[NUM_OF_CHARACTERS]` = number of characters from left side which you want to remove

If you want to remove from right side then use following

```
=SUBSTITUTE([TEXTCOLUMN_1],RIGHT([TEXTCOLUMN_1],[NUM_OF_CHARACTERS]),)
```