# Extracting delimited substring in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, string-manipulation

I started with [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/358486/excel-extract-substring-from-string), but it doesn't quite address my needs. I have a series of filenames in a worksheet. Some of the filenames have cross-references enclosed in square brackets. Consider `Foul language [see Angry Customer]`. We need to create a list of JUST the cross references, so what I need to do is build a statement that searches a field for `"["` or `"]"`. If neither is present, set the field to `""`. If both are present, extract the substring starting with `"["` and ending with `"]"`. For the time being, I'm not concerned with instances where there is an occurance of only ONE square bracket.

Here's where I am so far. The following statement works great and returns `[x-ref value]` where it should, but instances where there are no occurences of brackets default to `#VALUE!`. I'd like them to default to null or a single space. Is this even possible since `MID` is expecting two numeric parameters instead of null\space? I was **thinking** that the error would escape out of `MID` calculations and populate the cell with `""` BEFORE we got to the `start-position`.

`=MID(F11,(IFERROR((FIND("[",F11))," ")),(IFERROR(((FIND("]",F11))-((FIND("[",F11))-1))," ")))`

Tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close to the solution, this should do it:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("[",A1)+1,SEARCH("]",A1)-SEARCH("[",A1)-1),"")
```

Comment: Great answer. I was overthinking it...If I read this right, you're applying the `IFERROR` to the `MID` function rather than the `MID` function on a set of `IFFERROR(FIND...`. Am I looking at this correctly?

Comment: Yes - the background is that Excel will "forward" any error - so if any of the `SEARCH` functions return an error, `MID` will also result in an error. Therefore, we only need to capture any errors the `MID` produces, as this will include any of the `SEARCH`s...

Comment: That makes sense...now that I know how Excel internals work. :)  Thanks