# Find first string in text string that is numbers only. Formulas only

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, find, string

Is it possible to find the first string within a string that contains only numbers/digits? I have a few thousand addresses to process and some of them have Apartment numbers. I need to find the address number and extract it but the apartment number get extracted instead.

I was able to extract the first number string with this Formula, OneToZero is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}

```
=MID($A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(OneToZero,$A1),"")),FIND(" ",$A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(OneToZero,$A1),"")))-MIN(IFERROR(FIND(OneToZero,$A1),""))-0)
```

Returns this.

1417 Horne RD #1445A (Building 15) ----- **1417(Correct)**
Westwood #104A 801 Cantwell Ln --------- **104A(wrong)  801(Correct)**

I tried using

```
=MID($A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OneToZero," "&$A1),"")),FIND(" ",$A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OneToZero," "&$A1),"")))-MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OneToZero," "&$A1),""))-0)
```

But returns this if the first number doesn't have a non-digit character in front.

Westwood 104A  801 Cantwell Ln --------- **104A(wrong)  801(Correct)**

Cannot just remove the first string using the "#" due to it may say "Apt#" or just "104A".

Thank you.

Comment: uh, you need the first number string that is not grouped with a letter?

Comment: Yes. Was I not clear on that point? Only numbers, no other Characters besides 1234567890. TY   Is it possible to find the first string within a string that contains only numbers/digits?

Comment: I would start by taking a look at barry's answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15117291/1161309)

Comment: This would be simple in VBA, but a formula is a little bit more difficult.

Comment: Yeah that formula is only good if you want to split the string and extract the numbers, and that's only if it has anything other than numbers. And that won't be the string to begin with. The only sting needed to be retracted is the first one that has only numbers and only numbers.  I found this that tests the string but only after you found it. `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(--(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))),A1,"")` I Placed the Formula to find it in place of A1. I will post in the answers section.

Comment: @Raystafarian If you have a VBA solution I would like to see it. If you don't mind.

Comment: VBA solution example posted

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/358486/excel-extract-substring-from-string might be useful

Answer (score 1):

I found this to test the String

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(--(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))),A1,"")
```

and placed the code to locate the first string and second string.

Here is the entire thing. I don't know much about this, just pieced a bunch of different little snippets. I am now hoping that someone can help me streamline this.

```
    =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(--(MID(

MID([@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),"")),FIND(" ",[@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),"")))-MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),""))-0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(MID([@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),"")),FIND(" ",[@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),"")))-MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),""))-0)))),1)))),

MID([@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),"")),FIND(" ",[@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),"")))-MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),""))-0),

MID([@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin],FIND(" ",[@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),""))+0)),"")),FIND(" ",[@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin],FIND(" ",[@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),""))+0)),""))),"")))-MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin],FIND(" ",[@Origin],MIN(IFERROR(FIND(" "&OTZ," "&[@Origin]),""))+0)),""))),""))-0))
```

It is very long. I changed "OneToZero" is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0} to OTZ. [@Origin] is the column where the "raw data"(Unformatted Addresses) is.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Since you asked for an example of a VBA solution, this will print the first only numeric sub-string in the cell to the right -

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExtractStreetNumber()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const nullCharacter As String = " "
    Dim subString As String
    Dim fullAddress As String
    Dim subStringArray() As String
    Dim arrayPosition As Long
    Dim testCell As Range
    Dim addressTestRange As Range
    Set addressTestRange = Range("A1:A3") 'put your range of addresses here

    For Each testCell In addressTestRange
        fullAddress = testCell
        subStringArray = Split(fullAddress, nullCharacter)
        For arrayPosition = 0 To UBound(subStringArray)
            subString = subStringArray(arrayPosition)
            If IsNumeric(subString) Then
            testCell.Offset(, 1) = subString
            GoTo NextIteration
            End If
        Next
NextIteration:
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You could also create a user-defined function to use on the worksheet like `ExtractStreetNumber(A1)` -

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ExtractStreetNumber(ByVal fullAddress As String) As Long

    Const nullCharacter As String = " "
    Dim subString As String
    Dim subStringArray() As String
    Dim arrayPosition As Long

        subStringArray = Split(fullAddress, nullCharacter)
        For arrayPosition = 0 To UBound(subStringArray)
            subString = subStringArray(arrayPosition)
            If IsNumeric(subString) Then
                ExtractStreetNumber = subString
            Exit Function
            End If
        Next

End Function
```

Comment: Well they both work on my PC but not on the one that has all the data. The data cannot be transferred due to privacy issues. Any Macro or Function will simply not run on that PC. So VBA is not a solution and it will have to be Formula. Mine works but only bypasses the first two alphanumeric strings and is vary long.

Comment: @Mouthpear then it might be worthwhile to use text to columns on `space` and then test cells with `=ISNUMBER()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it with a formula, but you need to text to columns it and I'm blatantly ripping off [Scott's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1064615/116196) to a different question.

First I'd copy the data to a new sheet.

Go to `data - data tools - text to columns - delimited - space`

Now you can find the first only numeric substring in each row with something like

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:F1),COLUMN(A1:F1)))))
```

It's an array formula so you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Entr</kbd> and make sure it gets curly brackets.

Now you can copy - paste special the number back to the original sheet.

[image]

Comment: Yeah Text to Columns will not work. The address column is so different in format that it makes 10 or more different columns. And again this is a few thousand. Might as well do each individually. I tried doing the first 20 and by the time it takes to redoing all the columns and cutting pasting to the proper column.  It would be faster to edit each address in the origin than use text to columns. Plus every time a new address is added you would have to repeat the process.