# Where is the Longest String

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a small block of cells, say **C4** through **G11**.  The cells contain text of various lengths.  I can easily get the length of the longest string in the block with the array formula:

```
=MAX(LEN(C4:G11))
```

[image]

I need a formula to get the address of the cell with this longest string.  If there is more than one cell with the longest string, I need the address of the cell closest to the top the the block.  If the is more than one cell with the longest string in the same row, I need the address of the one closest to the left edge of the block.
In the above example the formula should return **E8**.

For this workbook, I can't use *VBA*. Any suggestions ??

Comment: Might [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22993487/1161309) help? It's for only one column though, but it's a starting point.

Comment: @Raystafarian  Thanks...............I will take a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it's Gary's Student:

```
=ADDRESS(MIN(IF(LEN($C$4:$G$11)=MAX(LEN($C$4:$G$11)),ROW($C$4:$G$11))),MIN(IF(LEN($C$4:$G$11)=MAX(LEN($C$4:$G$11)),COLUMN($C$4:$G$11))),4)
```

It is an array formula so Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

[image]

Comment: That's pretty crafty. I was wondering why you only comment answers.

Comment: Cool I was writing something to deserve my nick... too late :)

Comment: @Raystafarian I am generally a lazy person and if a comment will answer the question then I will use the shortest route. :)

Comment: I have to be perfectly honest, I don't understand how the IF array of true/false is matching up to the `row` and `column` formulas?

Comment: @ScottCraner...........This is **beautiful**...............thank you very much!

Comment: The row and column ranges are iterating in sync with the IF portion only the the row numbers or column number that line up with a true are then evaluated with the MIN.  The lowest is then returned to the Address function.  I probably made it worse.  @Raystafarian

Comment: Ah, I figured it was something like that, I guess that's because the row formula is being used as an array as well? So it's going `{4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5 ...`? That is beautiful.

Comment: And the column is going `{3,4,5,6,7,3,4,5,6,7}` I feel ignorant now. Anyway you got my +1